# Parallel efficiency drops inconsistently

Tags: c, performance, parallel-processing, mpi, cdf

My question is probably of trivial nature. I parallelised a CFD code using MPI libraries and now I am trying to investigate my parallel efficiency. To start with, I created a case which would provide equal loads among the ranks and constant ratio of volume of calculations over transferred data. Thus, my expectation would be that as I increase the ranks, any runtime changes would be attributed to the communication delays only.  However, I realised that subroutines that do not invoke rank communication (so they only do domain calculations, hence they deal with the same load for all ranks) contribute significantly-actually the most- runtime increases. What am I missing here? Does this even make sense?

Comment: Probably should post code that reproduces your problem. You can [edit] it into your question.

Comment: If your application is memory bound, then all the ranks on the same socket will share the same memory bandwidth. That would explain a drop in efficiency

Comment: Sorry Cody Gray, but I cannot share the code due to industrial property issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does this even make sense?

*Yes*!

The more processes you create ([every process has a rank](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/3agesw/can_someone_explain_to_me_what_an_mpi_rank_is/)), the more you reach the limit of your system's capability to execute processes in a truly parallel manner.

Your system (e.g. your computer) can run in parallel a certain amount of processes, when this limit is surpassed, then some processes wait to be executed (thus not all processes run in parallel), which harms performance.

For example, assuming that a computer has 4 cores and you create 4 processes, then every core can execute a process, thus your performance is harmed by the communicated between the processes, if any.

Now, in the same computer, you create 8 processes. What will happen?

4 of the processes will start execute in parallel, but the other 4 will *wait* for a core to get available, so that they can run too. This is not a truly parallel execution (some processes will execute in linear fashion). Moreover, depending on the OS scheduling policy, some processes may be interleaved, causing overhead at every switch.

Comment: Worse yet , they will be interleaved , causing overhead at every switch.

Comment: That would be madness @MadPhysicist. I updated the answer, do you like it now?

Comment: Crazy how nature do dat :-)

Comment: Even if you have the physical cores, the kernel and hardware still have to contend for shared resources. IIRC the paper I read said that once you hit about 20 CPUs, you lose about one whole CPU due to synchronization, and it gets much worse after that.

Comment: Yes I thought of that too @o11c, however I wasn't sure whether I should inject that into the answer or not..

Comment: Oh thanks very much. I see your point, that is why I made sure to not exceed the number of physical cores (32). So it seems o11c's addition is more fitted (btw which paper is that?). However, I just realised that hyper threading is turned on in the cluster. Would this cause efficiency issues although I am not exceeding the number of physical cores?